# DevExpress Xamarin grid use TextEdit field to filter grid

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, grid, devexpress

using/editing the C# and xaml code below, please help with my 2 questions.

1. is there a way to use DevExpress' Xamarin TextEdit's TextChanged event to filter an existing grid on the same page? Or a text field that's not DevExpress?
2. in the grid below, I have a template column with a button in it. How do I pass the Id of the customer (the row with the button clicked) to the button's function (SelectCustomer_Click).

xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<views:BasePage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"             
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LBA.LAMA.App.Views.CreateOrderPage"
             xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/xamarin/2014/forms/editors"
             xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/xamarin/2014/forms/datagrid"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:LBA.LAMA.App.ViewModels" 
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:LBA.LAMA.App.Views"
             x:DataType="vm:CreateOrderViewModel"
             x:TypeArguments="vm:CreateOrderViewModel"
             Title="{Binding Title}">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="40" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Enter Customer #, Name, or Email:"></Label>
            <dxe:TextEdit x:Name="filterTextEdit" TextChanged="FilterText_TextChanged" />

            <dxg:DataGridView x:Name="customerGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" SortMode="Multiple" ShowAutoFilterRow="True" IsReadOnly="True" CustomUnboundColumnData="customerGrid_UnboundCustTypeColumnData">
                <dxg:DataGridView.Columns>
                    <!--<dxg:TextColumn FieldName="Id" Caption="Id" Width="60" IsReadOnly="True" AllowAutoFilter="False" />-->
                    <dxg:TextColumn FieldName="CustomerName" Caption="Customer" Width="175" SortOrder="Ascending" SortIndex="0" />
                    <dxg:TextColumn FieldName="CustomerType" Caption="Business Type" UnboundType="String" Width="175" />
                    <dxg:TextColumn FieldName="Location" UnboundType="String" UnboundExpression="[City] + ' , ' + [Product.StateProvinceId]"  Width="250" />
                    <dxg:TemplateColumn FieldName="Id" Caption=" "  >
                        <dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Text="Write Order" Clicked="SelectCustomer_Click" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
                    </dxg:TemplateColumn>
                </dxg:DataGridView.Columns>
            </dxg:DataGridView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</views:BasePage>
```

xaml.cs

```
private async void SelectCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var x = sender;
    var y = e;
    var cust = _viewModel.SelectCustomerAsync(CartId);
}

private void FilterText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var txt = ((TextEdit)sender).Text;
}
```

Comment: their DataGrid supports filtering, why wouldn't you be able to set the filter criteria based on user input?

Comment: @Jason I am trying to have a text box above the grid where users can enter Customer info to filter the grid. Not all displayed Customer fields are in the grid that I want to filter on, for ex. Email is not a grid column, but I want to be able to filter on it

Comment: that appears to be a completely different question than what you actually asked

Comment: @Jason well I want to use the text edit or a basic text field to filter the grid. I dont see how that is different

Comment: Have you read their docs on filtering?  They're pretty extensive, with examples.  The simplest case is just to set the `FilterString` property based on what your user enters.  Whether or not you can filter on a value not displayed in the Grid, I have no idea.

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the feedback, xamarin and xaml are new to me, just realized I can access page elements from the code behind like older windows forms. I'll try that and come back if I have any other specific questions

Answer (score 0):

1. You can change FilterExpression of Grid like this:

   ```
    private void filterTextEdit_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var txt = ((TextEdit)sender).Text;
        customerGrid.FilterExpression = CriteriaOperator.Or(new BinaryOperator("Id", txt, BinaryOperatorType.Equal) ,CriteriaOperator.Parse("Contains([CustomerName], ?)", txt), CriteriaOperator.Parse("Contains([Email], ?)", txt));
    }
   ```

Beware of **txt** and **Id** DataType conversion!

2. It is hard to pass parameter to Click event. Many workarounds exists, but I use this Feature: https://docs.devexpress.com/MobileControls/DevExpress.XamarinForms.DataGrid.SwipeItem

---

Very useful is SwipeItems.

```
<dxg:DataGridView.StartSwipeItems>
            <dxg:SwipeItem Caption="Write order" BackgroundColor="#797bff" Image="Order.png" 
                               Tap="Swipe_ShowMM" />
        </dxg:DataGridView.StartSwipeItems>
```

with code

```
private void Swipe_ShowMM(object sender, SwipeItemTapEventArgs e)
{
    var mm = (e.Item as Customer);
    string Name = mm.CustomerName;
    var ID = mm.Id;
}
```